# How to connect wallet to the dapp within the iframe?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, phantom

I need to connect the dapp within the iframe. When I click on the connect wallet, it is not connecting within the iframe.

How can I connect the dapp within the iframe ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the Phantom [docs](https://docs.phantom.app/integrating/extension-and-in-app-browser-web-apps/detecting-the-provider), we currently do not provide injection in iFrames due to security reasons just yet.

You will have to use [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) element to get the injection in the web application.

Comment: Is there any example to inject with the window ?

Comment: Yes, you can find an example in our sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/phantom-labs/sandbox?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: The wallet is not being connected in this link of sandbox, any clue, how it is connected ?

Comment: Ah yes, you can simply open the link in the sandbox in another tab. As and how you make changes to the code in the sandbox, it will reflect in that dedicated tab

Comment: No, means when you open this link codesandbox.io/s/github/phantom-labs/sandbox?file=/src/App.tsx and click on the connect wallet button, it is not being connected to the wallet because there is no implementation of iframe in this and the code sandbox preview like browser is in the iframe.

Comment: Is there any example to connect the wallet with in the iframe ?